# Append UIView in UIScrollView after init by Masonry

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, masonry

I use the demo about UIScrollView,and I want to **append a UIView** a UIView after the UIScrollView init,like: I click a button,than there is a new UIView at the bottom of the UIScrollView. So I write the code like this:

```
- (void)clickButton{
    UIView *new = [[UIView alloc]init];
    new.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    new.mas_key = @"newView";

    [self.scrollView.contentView addSubview:new];
    [new mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.scrollView.lastBottom);
        make.left.equalTo(@0);
        make.right.equalTo(self.scrollView.contentView.mas_right);
        make.height.equalTo(@50);
    }];

    self.scrollView.lastBottom = new.mas_bottom;

    [self.scrollView.contentView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.scrollView.lastBottom);
    }];
}
```

But there still an error like

```
MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f97f431b360 UIView:content.bottom == UIView:newView.bottom
MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f97f4341400 UIView:newView.top == UIView:newView.bottom
MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f97f4341bb0 UIView:newView.height == 50
MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f97f4315390 UIView:content.bottom == UIView:newView.bottom

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f97f4341bb0 UIView:newView.height == 50
```

It means I didnot update my constraint after update.How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your view's frame is zero i think. you need to set position and size to view and your constraints should be like,.

scrollview : top,bottom,leading,trailing

view in scrollview (content view) : top,bottom,leading,trailing,horizontal center in container and fixed height

and your view (new) in container view : top,bottom,leading,trailing or as per requirement

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I use the Masonry (a framework about Autolayout),If I delete the `self.scrollView.lastBottom = new.mas_bottom;`,there is the block of the new UIView . But I cant move to the new UIView

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem.[robertjpayne](https://github.com/robertjpayne) respond my issue on Github.[Link here](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry/issues/341)